# symfony doctrine find User by Email

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

ok, with

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
->find($user_id)
```

I get an User by the given Identifier (ID).

but how can I get him by given email?

```
  $emailCheck = $em->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u, r')
        ->where('u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('email','test@email.com')
        ->getQuery();
```

Whill it return an array or an object? Is this the right way to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use the magic method of Doctrine findOneBy*your_field* or you can create your own method in your repo

```
public function findOneByEmailAndStoreId($email, $store_id)
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.email = :email')
        ->andWhere('c.store_id = :store_id')
        ->setParameter('email', $email)
        ->setParameter('store_id', $store_id)
        ->getQuery();
    return $q->getOneOrNullResult(); // will return only one result or null 'getResult' will return a collection
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return a `User` object.

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
    ->findOneByEmail($email);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use either

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
->findBy(array('email' => $email));
```

To load an array of User entities. (Will always be a list, even with 0 or 1 results.)

Or you can do:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
```

This will return the first found result as a User entity object.

You can use the `getOneOrNullResult()`, as well, it's the long variant. Note however that you should always use `setMaxResults(1)` with this, otherwise you'll get an exception if more than one result is found (SF 2.3.x).

Comment: great. So for example,if I'm searching for the client_id; I would use findOneByClientId or findOneByClient_id. just for better understanding